# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(img path));  

int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();
int[][] result = new int[height][width];

for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
     result[row][col] = image.getRGB(row, col);
  }
}
```

and this is the exception I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:301)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:871)
at PlantExtraction.main(PlantExtraction.java:46)
```

How can I remove these exceptions ?

Comment: run it in a debugger, so you can see which index is out of bounds when the exception is thrown. My guess is that row and column are reversed -- wouldn't the row be "Y" and the column be "X"?

Comment: IMHO the issue is at image.getRGB(row,col). See if row is related to height and col is related to width. To confirm you can limit row with width and col with height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code

```
image.getRGB(row, col);
```

Should be

```
image.getRGB(col, row);
```

As the documentation says:

`getRGB(int x, int y)`.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

(your `col` value is running upto `width` - which is the `x`-maximum of the image, so use `col` for `x` and `row` for `y`)